# Eigen error while initializing fixed size array

Tags: c++, eigen

I was following the Eigen documentation, b prints but a doesn't print.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std; 
using namespace Eigen; 


int main()
{

Vector3d b(5.0, 6.0, 7.0);


MatrixXi a {      // construct a 2x2 matrix
      {1, 2},     // first row
      {3, 4}      // second row
};

cout << b << endl; 

}
```

the error when I get when compiling and running with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen eigen.cpp -o eigen
```

```
 no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, -1>::Matrix(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   17 | };
      | ^
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:458,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from eigen.cpp:2:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting Eigen from my system first and then I cloned it from the git repository in a file called eigen I created in home folder. then I included the whole directory with

```
#include </home/zornic/eigen/eigen/Eigen/Dense>
```

and it worked, but I'm not sure why my headers didn't work like in the documentation in the eigen website.

Comment: The version you had installed probably was too old. Btw, you should `#include<Eigen/Dense>` (just `#include <Eigen/Core>` would be sufficient in your case), and compile with `-I/home/zornic/eigen/eigen` instead of writing the full path in your c++ file.